# Add javascript to webview JavaFX, a HTML Highlighter

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, webview, javafx

in some part of my program i want to load a webpage in webview JavaFX and use javascript codes to customize it. in this case I want to highlight some Words in webpage.

as i search, this website has the javascript code that in need (to highlight words): "[highlight: JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)" to use this code I should load in webview and after that use javascript commands to highlight words.

again as i searched, i found [this code on github](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3077942) that embed a JQuery to loaded webview.
so i combine those codes and create this:
(engine.executeScript parameter is highlight.js code)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class HtmlHighlighter extends Application {

    public static final String DEFAULT_JQUERY_MIN_VERSION = "1.7.2";
    public static final String JQUERY_LOCATION = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        WebView browser = new WebView();
        final WebEngine engine = browser.getEngine();

        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
                new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                        if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            System.out.println(engine.getDocument().getDocumentURI() + " was Successfully loaded");

                            executejQuery(engine, DEFAULT_JQUERY_MIN_VERSION, JQUERY_LOCATION, "$(\"a\").click(function(event){"
                                    + "  event.preventDefault();"
                                    + "  $(this).hide(\"slow\");"
                                    + "});");
                        }
                    }
                });

        engine.load("https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3077942");

        Button highlight = new Button("highlight");
        highlight.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                engine.executeScript("jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {\n"
                        + " function innerHighlight(node, pat) {\n"
                        + "  var skip = 0;\n"
                        + "  if (node.nodeType == 3) {\n"
                        + "   var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);\n"
                        + "   pos -= (node.data.substr(0, pos).toUpperCase().length - node.data.substr(0, pos).length);\n"
                        + "   if (pos >= 0) {\n"
                        + "    var spannode = document.createElement('span');\n"
                        + "    spannode.className = 'highlight';\n"
                        + "    var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);\n"
                        + "    var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);\n"
                        + "    var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);\n"
                        + "    spannode.appendChild(middleclone);\n"
                        + "    middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);\n"
                        + "    skip = 1;\n"
                        + "   }\n"
                        + "  }\n"
                        + "  else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {\n"
                        + "   for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {\n"
                        + "    i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);\n"
                        + "   }\n"
                        + "  }\n"
                        + "  return skip;\n"
                        + " }\n"
                        + " return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function() {\n"
                        + "  innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());\n"
                        + " }) : this;\n"
                        + "};\n"
                        + "\n"
                        + "jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function() {\n"
                        + " return this.find(\"span.highlight\").each(function() {\n"
                        + "  this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;\n"
                        + "  with (this.parentNode) {\n"
                        + "   replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);\n"
                        + "   normalize();\n"
                        + "  }\n"
                        + " }).end();\n"
                        + "}; $('body').highlight('t');");
            }
        });

        VBox v = new VBox(10);
        v.getChildren().setAll(browser, highlight);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(v));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Executes a script which may reference jQuery function on a document.
     * Checks if the document loaded in a webEngine has a version of jQuery
     * corresponding to the minimum required version loaded, and, if not, then
     * loads jQuery into the document from the default JQUERY_LOCATION.
     *
     * @param engine the webView engine to be used.
     * @Param jQueryLocation the location of the jQuery script to be executed.
     * @param minVersion the minimum version of jQuery which needs to be
     * included in the document.
     * @param script provided javascript script string (which may include use of
     * jQuery functions on the document).
     * @return the result of the script execution.
     */
    private static Object executejQuery(final WebEngine engine, String minVersion, String jQueryLocation, String script) {
        return engine.executeScript(
                "(function(window, document, version, callback) { "
                + "var j, d;"
                + "var loaded = false;"
                + "if (!(j = window.jQuery) || version > j.fn.jquery || callback(j, loaded)) {"
                + "  var script = document.createElement(\"script\");"
                + "  script.type = \"text/javascript\";"
                + "  script.src = \"" + jQueryLocation + "\";"
                + "  script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {"
                + "    if (!loaded && (!(d = this.readyState) || d == \"loaded\" || d == \"complete\")) {"
                + "      callback((j = window.jQuery).noConflict(1), loaded = true);"
                + "      j(script).remove();"
                + "    }"
                + "  };"
                + "  document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(script) "
                + "} "
                + "})(window, document, \"" + minVersion + "\", function($, jquery_loaded) {" + script + "});"
        );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(in this code i simply want to highlight letter 't')

but this code doesn't work correctly. i mean it only works on some pages! for example it works on "gist.github.com/jewelsea/3077942" or "stackoverflow.com" but it doesn't work on "wikipedia.org" or "sunset.usc.edu/Research_Group/barry.html" (i get errors such as "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object")

Where is the problem?
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Three things: Firstly, give us any and all error messages or debug output. Secondly, if you don't have debug output, put it in so you can see what the program is doing and where it's going wrong. Thirdly, never dump so much code on us -- give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can identify the problem more easily.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes sorry, i forgot to add error, i edit the question.
about 'MCVE', sorry again, i will read that page.

Comment: Still, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help greatly. When you make it, please put in small print statements so that you can see what the program does and track more easily where it goes wrong.